# How can I clear a run window while the program is running?

Tags: python

I have a code, and I want to be able to clear the run window after certain actions are performed, however I haven't been able to find a way to clear it aside from clearing it yourself using the `'clear all'` button(PyCharm btw). Is it possible to do that?

It seems that you can't clear the **pycharm terminal** without the clear button, however running it in `cmd`, the `os.system('cls')` or `os.system('clear')` works and will clear the screen.

Comment: which windows are you talking about? the console window where your program executes?

Comment: Is your script running in terminal, or you are using a GUI library?

Comment: Maybe `os.system('cls')` or `os.system('clear')`? depending on you platform.

Comment: I want to clear the window where the program executes @SembeiNorimaki

Comment: Use the suggestions provided by Axe319 to clear your console.

Comment: `os.system("clear")` would remove the text on the terminal where your code is running.

Comment: @Talon The script is running in terminal.

Comment: @Axe319 I have tried both of those however it does nothing. the text that was printed above it doesn't get cleared

Answer (score 1):

You can't clear the pycharm window without the clear all button, but the os.system('clear') will clear the window if you run it in cmd instead so use that instead..